# Opposite of PreventDefault() : Continuing ActionLink logic

Tags: ajax, json, preventdefault

```
<%: Html.ActionLink("Print", "Print", "Print", New With {.id = Model.ID}, New With {.target = "_blank", .class = "print"})%>
```

**How to return to my actionlink's functionality once preventDefault is called? ( the _blank page is not being opened on return)**

```
   $('#NameOfButton').bind('click', function (e) {
                   e.preventDefault(); // Stop click event

                    //Gather Data
                    var data = $(this).parents('form').first().serialize();

                    //Check Data , if saved to DB continue Click functionality
                    $.ajax({
                        url: '<%:Url.Action("Get")%>',
                        cache: false,
                        type: 'POST',
                        data: data,
                        success: function (result) {
                            if (result.Success == true) {
                                //return;
                                return true;
                            } else {
                                //do nothing
                                console.log('false');
                            }
                        }
                    });
                });
```

---

***Solution:***

```
 $('#NameOfButton').bind('click', function (e) {
                   e.preventDefault(); // Stop click event

                    //Gather Data
                    var el= $(this);
                    var data = $(this).parents('form').first().serialize();

                    //Check Data , if saved to DB continue Click functionality
                    $.ajax({
                        url: '<%:Url.Action("Get")%>',
                        cache: false,
                        type: 'POST',
                        data: data,
                        success: function (result) {
                            if (result.Success == true) {
                            window.location.href = el.attr('href');
                            } else {
                                //do nothing
                            }
                        }
                    });
                });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can trigger the event again:

```
 $('#NameOfButton').bind('click', function (e, skip) {
     if (skip) return; // check param

     e.preventDefault(); // Stop click event

     //Gather Data
     var data = $(this).parents('form').first().serialize();

     var el = $(this);
     //Check Data , if saved to DB continue Click functionality
     $.ajax({
         url: '<%:Url.Action("Get")%>',
         cache: false,
         type: 'POST',
         data: data,
         success: function (result) {
             if (result.Success == true) {
                 console.log('true');
                 el.trigger('click', [true]); // trigger same event with additional param
             } else {
                 //do nothing
                 console.log('false');
             }
         }
     });
 });
```

Comment: I have added the click Function parameter, the el instantiation, and the trigger on success = true lines, however when it fires again skip = undefined. Ideas?

Comment: So the event function loops forever?

Comment: No, it seems to not set $(this) to el correctly , on a consoleLog it spits out some object with true false values. When i do the same with el = e; it spits out the correct formatting for an actionlink element, however it displays `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function ` when it hits the line of  `el.trigger('click', [true]);` : all this is in the first iteration

Comment: What is the exact output of `console.log(el)` (called right after assign to `$(this)`)?

Comment: edited above, the assignment was my fault. However after the trigger hits it will check the skip variable and return to the function? - should i change return to return true; on the skip check?

Comment: You forgot about the `skip` argument declaration: `function (e, skip)`

Comment: Ill pay more attention from now on, however i get the same output.

Comment: Almost like its returning to the trigger that called the function rather than the action-link that called the function before.

Comment: Looks like code works. If `skip == true` then the function ends, so default action is invoked

Comment: have you read the comment above your last? - its returning back to where i called it from, being the trigger, not the action-link

Comment: Ok, I get it. I tested this solution with a `button` element. Unfortunately `a` elements don't react to fake triggers

Comment: So you can just replace `el.trigger('click', [true]);` line with `window.location.href = el.attr('href');`